# Parsing and manipulating Dates in a Json file using PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, date, timestamp

I need help parsing dates in a JSON file.

In a nutshell, my PowerShell script extracts information from a JSON source file into CSV.  My Json file has these fields:

```
[
    {
     "Type":  "Some String",
     "Score": "Some String" ,
     "Dateobtained": "2021-07-03T07:15:48.493",
     "Status": "Some String", 
     "Description": "Some String" 
    },
    { 
     "Type":  "Some String",
     "Score": "Some String" ,
     "Dateobtained": "2021-06-24T07:15:48.493",
     "Status": "Some String", 
     "Description": "Some String"
    }
]
```

I would like to filter out old information.  For instance, today is 6-July and I would only want to include information that was obtained this July only (`Dateobtained` should not extract data that is prior to July)

I already have this to extract the other information:

```
$json = Get-Content "source.json" | ConvertFrom-Json

$json | ForEach-Object {
# Iterate through each of the tests and create object for each
    $_.Findings| ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Type'       = $_.Type
            'Score'     = $_.Score
            'Status' = $_.Status
            'Description' = $_.Description
            }
    }
    
} | Export-Csv -Path "out.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I am not really sure on how to proceed in parsing that date, then limit what is outputted on the CSV file to the current month.

Thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following array:

```
PS /> $json | ft

Type        Score       Dateobtained            Status      Description
----        -----       ------------            ------      -----------
Some String Some String 2021-07-03T07:15:48.493 Some String Some String
Some String Some String 2021-06-24T07:15:48.493 Some String Some String
Some String Some String 2021-05-24T07:15:48.493 Some String Some String
Some String Some String 2021-04-24T07:15:48.493 Some String Some String
```

If you want to filter only those objects where `DateObtained` are between the current month (sorry for my English), you can do it like this:

```sh
$thisMonth = [datetime]::Today.Month

$json | Where-Object {

    ([datetime]$_.dateobtained).Month -eq $thisMonth
    # OR
    # ($_.dateobtained -as [datetime]).Month -eq $thisMonth

} |
Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty Dateobtained |
Export-Csv -Path "out.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

This would yield only one object (the first one):

```
Type        Score       Status      Description
----        -----       ------      -----------
Some String Some String Some String Some String
```

---

**Note:**

Type casting `[datetime]` on `$_.Dateobtained` could throw errors if said property does not have an actual date. If you're not sure, use **`$_.Dateobtained -as [datetime]`** instead:

```
PS /> [datetime]'notadate'
Cannot convert value "notadate" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0."
At line:1 char:1
+ [datetime]'notadate'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastParseTargetInvocationWithFormatProvider

PS /> 'notadate' -as [datetime] # // No errors here

PS />
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  `[datetime]$_.dateobtained).Month` helped me understand and manipulate the dates in my JSON file.

Comment: Im glad to help @prokopio_kuba, I hope the concept of type casting `[datetime]` vs using `-as` was clear too. If not let me know and ill try to explain it better.